# How can I grant the permission to Document AI specific processor?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

It seems that in Document AI the permission can only be granted to project level. How can I grant permission to lower level, like specific processor?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's only possible to grant IAM Permissions at the project level for Document AI. You cannot grant permissions at the processor level.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/access-control/iam-permissions

Refer to the [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/release-notes) for product updates.